# select items by pseudo class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with `id="myform"` and I am trying to style the html5 validation for it with a custom style for messages.

in vanilla js I'd write

```
invalidFields = form.querySelectorAll( ":invalid" )
```

where form is myform and I am selecting all the items that have the pseudo class :invalid.

Since I am working on a project that is using jQuery I want to rewrite this with jQuery.

I know that `$().each()` is the replacement for `querySelectorAll`. The problem is what to put in the first part of the statement.

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that jQuery `.each()` is the "replacement" for `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: @Pointy yes, I know what you mean. I was simplyfing the thing. You are right. It will replace the for loop that you use to iterate through the items

Comment: Did you not attempt to just copy it over to jQuery? That literally is what the answer is.... Did you get a error? What was your attempt?

Comment: @LelioFaieta also, many jQuery methods perform that iteration automatically without any need for `.each()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
form.querySelectorAll( ":invalid" )
```

in jQuery would be

```
$(':invalid',form)
```

To demonstrate:

```js
// Note this only uses .each for illustration
// has nothing to do with querySelectorAll as per original question

$('button').on("click",() => {
  var form = $('form');
  $(':invalid',form).each( (x,field) => console.log(field.id))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="field1" type="text" required>
  <input id="field2" type="text" required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```